# Graphql query is always returning null

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, express-graphql

I am trying to get course data using graphql, but server is always returning `null` as a response This is my code in file `server.js` :

```
var express=require('express');
const { graphqlHTTP } = require('express-graphql')
var {buildSchema}=require('graphql');

//graphql schema
var schema=buildSchema(`
type Query {
    course(id: Int!): Course
    courses(topic:String!):[Course]

}
type Course {
    id: Int
    title: String
    author: String
    description:String
    topic:String
    url: String
}
`);

var coursesData = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'The Complete Node.js Developer Course',
        author: 'Andrew Mead, Rob Percival',
        description: 'Learn Node.js by building real-world applications with Node, Express, MongoDB, Mocha, and more!',
        topic: 'Node.js',
        url: 'https://codingthesmartway.com/courses/nodejs/'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Node.js, Express & MongoDB Dev to Deployment',
        author: 'Brad Traversy',
        description: 'Learn by example building & deploying real-world Node.js applications from absolute scratch',
        topic: 'Node.js',
        url: 'https://codingthesmartway.com/courses/nodejs-express-mongodb/'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        title: 'JavaScript: Understanding The Weird Parts',
        author: 'Anthony Alicea',
        description: 'An advanced JavaScript course for everyone! Scope, closures, prototypes, this, build your own framework, and more.',
        topic: 'JavaScript',
        url: 'https://codingthesmartway.com/courses/understand-javascript/'
    }
]

//root resolver
var root= {
    course:getCourse,
    courses:getCourses
};


var getCourse= function (args){
    var id=args.id;
    console.log("delila")
    return coursesData.filter(course=>{
        return course.id==id
    })[0]

}
var getCourses = function(args){
    if(args.topic){
        var topic=args.topic;
        return coursesData.filter(course=>
            course.topic===topic
        );

    }
    else return coursesData
    
}
//create an experess server and graphql endpoint
var app=express();
app.use('/graphql', graphqlHTTP({
    schema: schema,
    rootValue:root,
    graphiql:true
}));
app.listen(4000,()=>console.log("delila express graphql server running on localhost 4000"))
```

When I go to `localhost:4000/graphql` to get data I am using

```
query getSingleCourse($courseID: Int !){
  course(id:$courseID){
    title
    author
    description
    url
    topic
  }
}

{
  "courseID": 3
}
```

But I am constantly getting result `null`. Look at image
[image]

Anyone idea why is happening this? Server should return course with `id 3` but obviously there is something that I am missing

Comment: 'args' is a 2nd resolver fn arg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define function expression first and then use them. That's the reason.

> Function expressions in JavaScript are not hoisted, unlike function declarations. You can't use function expressions before you create them:

See [Function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function)

E.g.

```js
//...

var getCourse = function (args) {
  var id = args.id;
  console.log('delila');
  return coursesData.filter((course) => {
    return course.id == id;
  })[0];
};
var getCourses = function (args) {
  if (args.topic) {
    var topic = args.topic;
    return coursesData.filter((course) => course.topic === topic);
  } else return coursesData;
};

//root resolver
var root = {
  course: getCourse,
  courses: getCourses,
};

//...
```